# Not spinning full circle css animation

Tags: css, animation

I am try to create a spinning image horizontally using purely CSS3.

This is a link to my page

http://www.csupomona.edu/~lannguyen/ISSM_WEB/html/

This is the css file:

www.csupomona.edu/~lannguyen/ISSM_WEB/css/main.css

the spin caller is at the top, and the implementation is at the bottom.

My issue is that the spinning that CSS3 provided is not full rotation. I would like some thing like this

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-cube.php (the depth cube example, but no need 3D).

can anyone help please.

thanks

Comment: In your code, you have deg set to 320, not 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/X6yu3/1/)

```
    <div class="cube">TRY</div>
```

CSS

```
.cube {
background-color: #5F9EA0;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style:preserve-3d; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d; /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
width: 200px;
}

 @keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotateY(0); 
    -ms-transform:rotateY(0); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(0); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
to { transform: rotateY(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotateY(360deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
}

.cube {
animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation:spin 5s infinite linear;
-ms-animation:spin 5s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
from { transform: rotateY(0); 
    -ms-transform:rotateY(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotateY(0); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
to { transform: rotateY(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotateY(360deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
}
```

Comment: -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
This line is really important in safari to prevent strange polygons in circle when rotate, lol. Thanks guy!